# Using Image.show() fails because the temporary file written does not exist (Windows 10, Pillow 9.0.1)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have seen this post for Ubuntu 20.04 and Pillow version 9.0.0 but the problem now exists on my Windows machine running Python 3.9.12 locally. What is weird is that it has worked fine the last two weeks and decided today to delete a temporary photo immediately after displaying it to me and therefore blocking me from seeing it.

My code is as follows though I believe it does not matter

```
if file[file.index('.')+1:] == "jpg" or file[file.index('.')+1:] == "png": #only jpg and png files
        totalImages += 1
        img = Image.open(str(pathArg2) + '/' + file) #opens the image
        exif_date = img.getexif().get(306) #gets the date from the exif data
        if exif_date != None:
            for coord in locations:
                for time in coord.time:
                    if exif_date[0:15] == time[0:15]: #if the creation time of the image up to a 10 minute interval is the same as the time of the location
                        address = locator.reverse(coord.coords).address #gets the address of the location
                        image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
                        image_editable.text((15,15), address, fill = (170, 255, 0), font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", int((img.width*img.height) ** (1./4.)))) #adds the address text to the image
                        img.show()
                        print("Was the address correct? (y/n)")
                        answer = input("> ")
                        while answer != "y" and answer != "n": #checks if the address is correct with the user
                            answer = input("> ")
                        if answer == "y":
                            imagesCorrectlyAnnotated += 1
                            img.close()
                            return True
                        else:
                            imagesIncorrectlyAnnotated += 1
                            img.close()
                            img = Image.open(str(pathArg2) + '/' + file)
                        imagesAnnotated += 1
```

time.sleep() does not do anything either but that is what I thought would be the case

Commenting out code below img.show() does not change the behavior.

If I run even a simple python program to show an image such as

```
from PIL import Image
import time
img = Image.open('TestImages/20211203_175356.jpg')
img.show()
time.sleep(30)
```

It still shows and then immediately removes the images and says its been deleted, even if the program is still running

Comment: Please post code as text and ensure that it is a [mcve].

Comment: Just edited. Sorry for that. Put a bit more clarification as well